# Django template: change id for form in the for loop

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Model and a Form as below

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Comment
        fields = ('text',)

        widgets = {
            'text': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'comment-text',
                'required': True,
                'placeholder': 'Say something...'}),
        }
```

And in the Django template, I want to use this form several times in a for loop but each iteration I want to change the id of the text in the loop. Currently I am using below code

```
{% for post in post_queryset %}
   {% csrf_token %}
   {% bootstrap_form formComment %}
{% endfor %}
```

can someone help me to change the code so that id will change each time in the loop.

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to change the id of the HTML input element in each form in the for loop?

Comment: Yes, I want to change id of the HTML input.

Comment: And is this so you can target each one serpartly with javascript or css?

Comment: Yes, I want to use JavaScript to get entered input value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change a surrounding element and target them through that one. I'm using a [forloop variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for) given to you buy the template tag `for`. But you could use a `post` attribute but I don't know what your model looks like.

```
{% for post in post_queryset %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="post-{ forloop.counter }">    
        {% bootstrap_form formComment %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: My main goal is get the entered values in Javascript to submit form with AJAX like this   
$.ajax({
        url : "create_comment/", 
        type : "POST", 
        data : { the_comment : $('#comment-text').val(),

Do you think it is possible if use the surrounding element tag. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah you can dill down through the DOM just like with css. It would be somehting like `$('#post-1 #comment-text).val()`. Check out https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/